# Trying to Update a list inside an entity gives me always an error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-7.0

I'm using a domain driven design. There is a relation between 2 entities:

Expense and Employee

Expense has a list of Employees

Expense:

```
private List<Employee> _Employees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();
public List<Employee> Employees => _Employees;
```

Employees does not have a reference to Expense. I don't need to access expense by employee.

When I create an expense I am able to add Employees. I'm able to remove Employees by using this in a repository of Employee.

```
public void RemoveRange(List<Employee> Employee)
{
   _context.Set<Employee>().RemoveRange(Employee);
}
```

But when doing an update to an Expense I receive an error: "The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since"

Fetch expense first for tracking and then changing the employees:

```
public async Task<Expense?> Get(Guid id)
{
        return await _context.Set<Expense>()
            .Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .Include(x => x.Employees)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
...
var expense = await _repoExpense.Get(expenseId);
foreach (var Employee in m.Value.Employees)
{
   var Emplyoee= Employee.Create(Employee.EmployeeName,, Employee.EmployeeId, Employee.CompanyName);
   expense.AddEmployee(Emplyoee);
}
await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(ct); //error line
```

This foreach is exactly the same I use when creating a new expense with Employees and it works. Just not when updating.

I have tried other ways but the error is always the same. I don't care much about the previous data on List Employee. What I do is remove every record and add new ones. When creating a new expense it works fine. When I grab an existing Expense, clear its Employees and add new ones...it breaks. Even if I just add and don't remove before...it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

When updating references to related one-to-many relationships you should not try to take the approach of replacing collections. While it may be simpler from a coding perspective, it is worst from a EF/Database one. Something like an expense to employee relationship would generally be a many-to-many relationship where expenses *reference* employees, not encapsulate employees. To outline the difference take something like a Customer and Order. A Customer contains many Orders, but each order belongs to just one Customer. Different customers can order the same things, but each order is a unique row in the database. An Expense may reference many Employees, but in reality those same employees should be able to be referenced by different Expenses, should they not?  You may be running foul by trying to associate existing employees to new expenses while telling EF that the relationship is one-to-many (parent-child) instead of many-to-many. (association) One-to-Many would have an ExpenseId on the Employee table meaning an employee can only ever be associated with one expense. To allow multiple expenses to reference the same employee, you need to define something like an ExpenseEmployee table and tell EF that it is a many-to-many relationship. This can still be one-way references where Expense contains an Employees collection but there is no Expenses collection on the Employee.

Your example code also will not compile as you are using the same variable name "Employee" for the iteration and the new employee, your example also does not clear the employees list. It generally helps to post actual code rather than a re-interpretation/simplification as your re-hashed code may not contain the actual problem.

For instance instead of something like this:

```
var expense = await _repoExpense.Get(expenseId);
expense.Employees.Clear();
foreach (var employee in m.Value.Employees)
{
   var newEmplyoee= Employee.Create(employee.EmployeeName, employee.EmployeeId, employee.CompanyName);
   expense.Employees.Add(Emplyoee);
}
```

it is better to do it more explicitly. Determine what employees need to be removed and added, then make those adjustments:

```
var expense = await _repoExpense.Get(expenseId);
var existingEmployeeIds = expense.Employees.Select(x => x.EmployeeId).ToList();
var updatedEmployeeIds = m.Value.Employees.Select(x => x.EmployeeId).ToList();

var employeeIdsToAdd = updatedEmployeeIds.Except(existingEmployeeIds).ToList();
var employeeIdsToRemove = existingEmployeeIds.Except(updatedEmployeeIds).ToList();
```

Next, removing the de-referenced employees is easy:

```
if(employeeIdsToRemove.Any())
{
    var employeesToRemove = expense.Employees
        .Where(x => exmployeeIdsToRemove.Contains(x.EmployeeId))
        .ToList();
    foreach(var employee in employeesToRemove)
        expense.Employees.Remove(employee);
}
```

Lastly, to add the references to the employees to add. Here we are dealing with references to existing employee records, not creating new employees, so we need to ensure that we are associating entities that the DbContext will recognize as existing employee records. If you `new` up an employee with the ID and other fields, EF will treat that as a `INSERT` since it isn't tracking that instance and won't recognize it is supposed to be an existing reference. So we fetch those employees:

```
if (employeeIdsToAdd.Any())
{
     var employeesToAdd = await _context.Employees
         .Where(x => employeeIdsToAdd.Contains(x.EmployeeId))
         .ToListAsync();
     foreach(var employee in employeesToAdd)
         expense.Employees.Add(employee);
}

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

... and that is it. Now this poses one problem, your repository pattern. You will need to fetch the employees from the DbContext for the IDs that are added. This is where using a repository pattern over EF can be counter-productive as EF already provides a repository in the form of the `DbSet`. Worst case if you only have a Get() method to get by ID you are going to have to iterate over the Ids to Add and get each one to add, or introduce a Get method with a `params int[] ids` to be able to fetch multiple rows by ID.

Comment: The reason I don't care about the employees and can have actually the same employeeId on various records is because this data "truthiness" comes from an external service that I don't fully trust. So it is mostly for a record of what was the data at the moment it was saved. I have a GUID for each Employee in reality that makes the reference. EmployeeId is what comes from the external data.

Comment: Ok, so in that case Employee can be treated as a child, can you update your question with the Expense and Employee entity definitions? I would expect that the employee entity has an ExpenseId and an Id as it's PK (being this Guid value, either initialized or set as an Identity /w the DB handling new values) Are you calling that employee repo RemoveRange with the DbContext without a SaveChanges prior or after loading the Expense /w Employees? If so that will likely cause an issue due to tracked references.